Proving $\sum\limits_{k\ge0}\frac1{2k+2}\left[\frac1{2^{2k}(1-2k)}\binom{2k}k\right]^2=\frac{16}{9\pi}$
Whilst looking at Jack's answer to this question, he claims that
$$\sum_{k\geq 0}\frac{1}{2k+2}\left[\frac{1}{2^{2k}(1-2k)}\binom{2k}{k}\right]^2=\frac{16}{9\pi}$$
and, as suggested by OP, this result can be found employing contour integration and the power series appearing there. Next up I'll attach my attempt and where I left it at:
\begin{align*}
&\quad\sum_{k\geq 0}\frac{1}{2k+2}\left[\frac{1}{2^{2k}(1-2k)}\binom{2k}{k}\right]^2\\
&=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\sum_{k\geq 0}\sum_{\ell\geq 0}\left[\frac{1}{2\ell+2}\frac{1}{4^\ell}\binom{2\ell}{\ell}\right]\left[\frac{1}{(2k-1)^2}\frac{1}{4^k}\binom{2k}{k}\right]\oint_{|z|=1} z^{2k-2\ell-1}\,\mathrm dz\\
&=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_{|z|=1}\frac{\mathrm dz}{z}\left(\sum_{k\geq 0}\frac{1}{(2k-1)^2}\frac{1}{4^k}\binom{2k}{k}z^{2k}\right)\left(\sum_{\ell\geq 0}\frac{1}{2\ell+2}\frac{1}{4^\ell}\binom{2\ell}{\ell}\left(\frac{1}{z}\right)^{2\ell}\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_{|z|=1}\frac{\mathrm dz}{z}\left(\sqrt{1-z^2}+z\arcsin(z)\right)\left(z^2-z\sqrt{z^2-1}\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_{|z|=1}\mathrm dz\,\left(z\sqrt{1-z^2}+z^2\arcsin(z)-\sqrt{1-z^2}\sqrt{z^2-1}-z\sqrt{z^2-1}\arcsin(z)\right)
\end{align*}
I don't know how to compute these last integrals or even if I'm going in the right path...

Using the usual notation for Pochhammers symbols $(a)_n=a(a+1)(a+2)\cdots (a+n-1)=\Gamma(a+n)/\Gamma(a)$, $\Gamma$-function
duplication formulas and Gaussian Hypergeometric functions (and their special values)
$$
\sum_{k\ge 0} \frac{1}{2k+2} \frac{1}{2^{4k}(1-2k)^2} \binom{2k}{k}^2
$$
$$
=\sum_{k\ge 0} \frac{1}{2k+2} \frac{1}{2^{4k}(1-2k)^2} \frac{\Gamma^2(2k+1)}{\Gamma^4(k+1)}
$$
$$
=\frac{1}{8}\sum_{k\ge 0} \frac{1}{k+1} \frac{1}{(1/2-k)^2} \frac{\Gamma^2(2k+1)}{\Gamma^3(k+1)}\frac{1}{2^{4k}k!}
$$
$$
=\frac{1}{8}\sum_{k\ge 0} \frac{(1)_k}{(2)_k} \frac{1}{(k-1/2)^2} \frac{\Gamma^2(2k+1)}{\Gamma^3(k+1)}\frac{1}{2^{4k}k!}
$$
$$
=\frac{1}{8}\sum_{k\ge 0} \frac{(1)_k}{(2)_k} \frac{[(-1/2)_k]^2}{[(-1/2)(1/2)_k]^2} \frac{\Gamma^2(2k+1)}{\Gamma^3(k+1)}\frac{1}{2^{4k}k!}
$$
$$
=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k\ge 0} \frac{(1)_k}{(2)_k} \frac{[(-1/2)_k]^2}{[(1/2)_{k}]^2} \frac{[(1)_{2k}]^2}{[(1)_k]^3}\frac{1}{2^{4k}k!}
$$
$$
=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k\ge 0} \frac{(1)_k}{(2)_k} \frac{[(-1/2)_k]^2}{[(1/2)_{k}]^2} \frac{[(1/2)_k(1)_k2^{2k}]^2}{[(1)_k]^3}\frac{1}{2^{4k}k!}
$$
$$
=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k\ge 0} \frac{1}{(2)_k} \frac{[(-1/2)_k]^2}{[(1/2)_{k}]^2} \frac{[(1/2)_k]^22^{4k}}{1}\frac{1}{2^{4k}k!}
$$
$$
=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k\ge 0} \frac{1}{(2)_k} \frac{[(-1/2)_k]^2}{1} \frac{2^{4k}}{1}\frac{1}{2^{4k}k!}
$$
$$
=\frac{1}{2}{}_2F_1(-1/2,-1/2 ; 2;1)
$$
$$
=\frac{1}{2}\frac{32}{9\pi}
$$
where we have used https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function
$$
_2F_1(a,b;c;1) = \frac{\Gamma(c)\Gamma(c-a-b)}{\Gamma(c-a)\Gamma(c-b)}
$$
q.e.d.

Is their any reference on that last value of $_2 F_1(-1/2,-1/2;2;1)$?
